# Angular 4 Json to Excel or csv

Tags: json, excel, angular, csv, json2xls

So I have a large data chunk I want to export to work on excel, I have tried angular2-json2csv and angular2-csv and they download the data to a csv file but the issue is that I have several includes into my data format, nested objects that return from my entity framework response like:

```
{
 name,
 personId,
 person,
 eventId,
 event
}
```

so when I download the data i get something like this:

```
name, personId, person, eventId, event
"George", "1", [Object, object], "32", [Object, object]
```

so how can I work with the nested json data to be displayed on my csv files. any pointer would be greatly appreciated!